# Collision Handling For Large Data Sets?

Tags: python, algorithm, collision-detection, simulation, scientific-computing

I am working on some rather computation heavy simulations regarding the collapse and formation of galaxies. In creating that simulation, I have defined `class Particle`, which possesses all of the necessary physics for handling the simulation, and then from that constructed the `class Particle_Cloud`, which is principally a grouping of particle objects.

On each repetition of the animation sequence, I utilize `Particle_Cloud.update(dt)` to calculated the positional changes and whatnot. The issue occurs in handling particle collisions. As it stands, I have created the function as follows:

```
        part_sims = []
        """
        Removing merged particles
        """
        new_particles = [] #This list will contain the merged particles
        for part in self.particles: #iteration through all particles
            if part in self.particles: #Checking to make sure the particle is actually still there.
                non_self_particles = [i for i in self.particles if i != part] #all of the particles which are not part.
                part_sims = []
                for i, j in enumerate([part.distance(k) < self.size_parameter for k in non_self_particles]):
                    if j == True and non_self_particles[i] in self.particles:
                        part_sims.append(i)
                        try:
                            self.particles.remove(part)
                        except:
                            pass
                        new_particles.append(part + non_self_particles[i])

            else:
                pass
        for removed_particle in part_sims:
            self.particles.remove(non_self_particles[removed_particle])
        for i in new_particles:
            self.particles.append(i)
```

In a nutshell, I created a list `new_particles` to contain the combinations, and then iterated through every combination to figure out which particles needed to combine. Finally, I added the `new_particles` to `self.particles` and deleted the removable particles.

The issue is this: I can't seem to get this to work universally. For the most part, this fails when particles are close together, and I cannot figure out why. It is also woefully inefficient. Does anyone know a better method?

Comment: As a general rule, you're not gonna get efficiency using Python classes. From the sound of the problem (modelling the universe!!), you'll need to abstract away the class structure and get it into numpy arrays.

Comment: Or switch languages. Performance is one reason much game programming (which includes high performance collision detection) is done in C++ or C.